# How to create your own babel processor alternative to `React`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, babeljs

When you use JSX in a JS file, you have to import `React` or else the generated code won't compile. This is because this:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

function Foo() { return 'hello world' }

ReactDOM.render(<Foo/>, document.body)
```

Becomes:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

function Foo() { return 'hello world' }

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Foo), document.body)
```

So the `React` in `React.createElement` is getting generated by some babel or webpack tooling somewhere, and it is specified somewhere which I don't remember. My question is first where is this specified that it translates the JSX into `React.createElement`?

Second, and main question, is how can I customize this to instead translate the JSX into `MyThing.create`? I remember seeing this a long time ago with the `virtual-dom` library, but I've since forgotten. Wondering what it takes to do this.

What I would like to do is create an API something like this

```
<Foo/>
<Bar/>
<Baz/>

MyThing.create('Foo')
MyThing.create('Bar')
MyThing.create('Baz')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Babel plugin responsible for JSX processing is [`@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx). Despite its React-specific name, you can use any *pragma* you like (`React.createElement` is the default pragma) by setting an option in your `.babelrc` file:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
    "plugins": [
        ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx", {
            "pragma": "MyThing.create"
        }]
    ]
}
```

In addition to `pragma`, there's `pragmaFrag` to set what the output should be for `<>...</>` JSX structures. (The default is `React.Fragment`.)

For example, [Mithril.js](https://mithril.js.org/jsx.html) uses `"pragma": "m"` and `"pragmaFrag": "'['"`. [Preact](https://preactjs.com) uses `"pragma": "Preact.h"` and `"pragmaFrag": "Preact.Fragment"`.

~5 years ago I played with a different JSX-to-JavaScript compiler which worked quite well, but I can't find it now. Which makes sense: JavaScript has changed a lot in the last five years, and the time commitment to keep the compiler up-to-date with those changes would be non-trivial. It's easy to see a dev deciding not to pursue it given the success of Babel.

There is one alternative I know of: [Sucrase](https://github.com/alangpierce/sucrase). It **only** compiles JSX, TypeScript, and Flow, without Babel's plugin structure. (As a result, it's ***very*** fast.)

Comment: Thanks for the rec on Sucrase, that looks great! How do I go about creating a plugin so I can get rid of that pragma, just copy the code from @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx?

Comment: Also, can you use both `React` pragma and `MyThing` pragma side by side? That is, say you have 1000 file app, half in react and half in mything, all mixed together into one build. Can you have it be that the build uses 2 different pragmas?

Comment: @LancePollard - I'm not *recommending* Sucrase, I've never used it, just know it exists. :-) I'm not sure why you'd want to avoid the `pragma` option, but yes, you could copy the plugin, change its name, and change the default. But then you're taking aboard the work of keeping your copy up-to-date, merging in later PRs, etc. FWIW, other projects seem happy to just use the configuration of the existing plugin (e.g., Mithril.js and Preact).

Comment: @LancePollard - `.babelrc` is file-relative, so you can have a directory in your project for React files and another directory for MyThing files. Definitions in the directory-specific `.babelrc` files are merged with a project-wide `.babelrc` file, so you don't have to duplicate everything. Details [in the `.babelrc` documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#file-relative-configuration).

Comment: follow up question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57128615/how-to-get-custom-react-babel-pragma-to-pass-string-as-argument-rather-than-func